# Assigning value to struct variable

Tags: c, struct

I am constructing a adjacency list that I am using to make a directed graph. I read two characters and then make a vertex out of each of them unless a vertex with that char has already been made. I am unfamiliar with structures so this is tripping me up. The values aren't being assigned and I am ending up with an empty list. I am assuming that it is something that has to do with pointers that I am overlooking but I can't seem to find the problem. I hope that someone can help. I will include my code and a sample output.

my.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* Forward declaration */
struct EDGETAG;

typedef struct
{
    char c;
    bool isVisited;
    struct EDGETAG* p;
} VERTEX;

typedef struct EDGETAG
{
    VERTEX* v;
    struct EDGETAG* q;
} EDGE;


int main (int argc, char* argv[]);

int adjListSearch (char a, int size, VERTEX* adjList);
```

adjListSearch.c

```
#include "my.h"

int adjListSearch (char a, int size, VERTEX* adjList)
{

int i;


if(size == 0)
{
printf("empty\n");
return 1;
}

for(i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if( adjList[i].c = a)
    {
    return 0;
    printf("found\n");
    }
}
printf("notfound\n");
return 1;

}
```

main.c

```
#include "my.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{




int y = 0;
int x = 0;
VERTEX *adjList;
adjList  = (VERTEX*)calloc(26, sizeof(VERTEX));
//adjList = malloc(sizeof(VERTEX)*26);
FILE* p;
char *fp;
char a;
char b;
int check1 = 0;
int check2 = 0;
int size = 0;
int searchsuccess = 0;
int i;
//Statements



p = fopen( argv[1], "r");



while(fscanf(p," %c %c", &a, &b)!= EOF)  
{
printf("a: %c b: %c\n",a,b);

    check1 = adjListSearch(a,size,adjList);

    if(check1==1)
    {

        adjList[size].c = a;
        size = size +1;

    }   
        //printf("%c\n", adjList[size].c);  

    check2 = adjListSearch(b,size,adjList);
    if(check2==1)
    {
        adjList[size].c = b;
        size = size +1;
    }

}
//End While
printf("Size: %d", size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
printf("%c\n", adjList[size].c);
}


free(p);


return 0;
}
//End main
```

Sample Output

```
a: A b: B
a: B b: C
a: E b: X
a: C b: D
Size: 1
```

As you can see none of the characters are printed as being inside a structure.

**EDIT 1:**

```
I would want the expected output to look like 
a: A b: B
a: B b: C
a: E b: X
a: C b: D
Size: 6
A
B
C
E
X
D
```

**Edit 2**
Still lost on this if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a variety of problems.

1. You should use `fclose(p);` and not `free(p);`.
2. You should print `printf("%c\n", adjList[i].c);` instead of `printf("%c\n", adjList[size].c);`.
3. As [brokenfoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755108/brokenfoot) pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122819/15168), you need to compare `a` instead of assign it in `adjListSearch()`.
4. There were multiple unused variables (the compilation options I use complain about them).
5. There is no need to declare `main()` (though it doesn't do any harm to the program).
6. You don't check that there is an `argv[1]` to use.
7. You don't check that you opened the file.
8. You should really use `while (fscanf(p, " %c %c", &a, &b) == 2)`, though it would only matter in this program if there were an odd number of characters to process.  At least you were testing `fscanf()` which is more than many questions we see do.

In the code below, I printed more informative status messages.

#### main.c

```
#include "my.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    VERTEX *adjList;
    adjList  = (VERTEX *)calloc(26, sizeof(VERTEX));
    FILE *p;
    char a;
    char b;
    int check1 = 0;
    int check2 = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int i;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((p = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(p, " %c %c", &a, &b) == 2)
    {
        printf("a: %c b: %c\n", a, b);

        check1 = adjListSearch(a, size, adjList);

        if (check1 == 1)
        {
            printf("Adding a = %c\n", a);
            adjList[size++].c = a;
        }
        check2 = adjListSearch(b, size, adjList);
        if (check2 == 1)
        {
            printf("Adding b = %c\n", b);
            adjList[size++].c = b;
        }
    }
    printf("Size: %d\n", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", adjList[i].c);
    }

    fclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

#### adjListSearch.c

```
#include "my.h"

int adjListSearch(char a, int size, VERTEX *adjList)
{
    int i;

    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("empty\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (adjList[i].c == a)
        {
            printf("found %c\n", a);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("not found %c\n", a);
    return 1;
}
```

#### Data

```
A B
B C
E X
C D
```

#### Sample output

```
a: A b: B
empty
Adding a = A
not found B
Adding b = B
a: B b: C
found B
not found C
Adding b = C
a: E b: X
not found E
Adding a = E
not found X
Adding b = X
a: C b: D
found C
not found D
Adding b = D
Size: 6
A
B
C
E
X
D
```

Comment: This was a very informative answer and helped me very much. I appreciate how well you presented the information.

Answer (score 1):

In `adjListSearch()`, change

```
if( adjList[i].c = a)
```

to

```
if( adjList[i].c == a)
```

Comment: That helped but I still can't seem to print out the char part of the VERTEX structure to see if there is actually anything there.

Comment: @Fluxxxy: Can you post the expected output as well ?

Comment: I have added it to my original post at the bottom.